# Converting Javascript to C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to convert the following JavaScript code:

```js
var Js_white = 0;
var Js_black = 1;

var Js_knightMvt = new Array();         //new int[2][64];
var Js_bishopMvt = new Array();         //new int[2][64];

function BoardCpy(a: Array, b: Array):void
    {
      for( var sq= 0; sq < 64; sq++ ) b[sq] = a[sq]; 
    }

  another function
  {
    BoardCpy(Js_knight_pos, Js_knightMvt[Js_white]);
      BoardCpy(Js_knight_pos, Js_knightMvt[Js_black]);
      BoardCpy(Js_bishop_pos, Js_bishopMvt[Js_white]);
      BoardCpy(Js_bishop_pos, Js_bishopMvt[Js_black]);
  }
```

to C# like this:

```cs
private static int Js_white = 0;
private static int Js_black = 1;

private int[] Js_knightMvt;               //new int[2][64];
private int[] Js_bishopMvt;               //new int[2][64];

private void BoardCpy(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        for (int sq = 0; sq < 64; sq++)
        {
            b[sq] = a[sq];
        }
    }

Another function
{
  BoardCpy(Js_knight_pos, Js_knightMvt[Js_white]);
  BoardCpy(Js_knight_pos, Js_knightMvt[Js_black]);
  BoardCpy(Js_bishop_pos, Js_bishopMvt[Js_white]);
  BoardCpy(Js_bishop_pos, Js_bishopMvt[Js_black]);
}
```

The problem is I get

> error CS1503: Argument '#2' cannot convert 'int' expression to type 'int[]' and error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'JsJester.BoardCpy(int[], int[])' has some invalid arguments on the lines from another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want each of these two arrays to be a [jagged array of arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays):

```
private int[] Js_knightMvt; //new int[2][64];
private int[] Js_bishopMvt; //new int[2][64];
```

But you've defined them as an array of `int`s.

That means when you select one index from one of these arrays, you get a single integer, rather than an array of integers.

If you want each entry of these `Mvt` arrays to contain its own array, then you need to specify that in the type:

```
 // Two sets of brackets for the two layers of arrays
 int[][] Js_knightMvt = new int[2][];
```

Remember to create each nested array inside this container before you try to use them, eg...

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      JS_knightMvt[i] = new int[64];
 }
```

Without this, all of the entries of the outer array will just contain `null` by default.

Comment: thank for your answer. I figured out by myself in the mean type now I have problems with arrays declared as chars which = integers and declaration of arrays from int[] to int[][]

Comment: I'm not sure what you need; can you be more specific?

Comment: I changed                                                                                                  
private int[] Js_knightMvt;               //new int[2][64];
private int[] Js_bishopMvt;               //new int[2][64]; to                                                 private int[][] Js_knightMvt and Js_bishopMVt and solved all the puzzle